# How to use native Json with Flash?

Tags: flash, haxe

Not sure if this is a Haxe or a Flash question.

I'm using Haxe 2.10.

I'd like to use the haxe.Json class.

For this it seems I need to compile for Flash Player 11, at least. Otherwise JSON is not found on execution time and I get an exception.

So I compiled my swf lib for Flash Player 11.2 (previously it was for Flash 9), and changed my compilation line to:

```
-main Client.hx
-swf-version 11.2
-swf client.swf
```

Now, I have the JSON unfound in Flash (testing with Flash Player 11.7 debug).
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Update: compiling with -D haxeJSON works (uses Haxe implementation), but it's only a workaround, I'd like to use the native one if possible.